# jQuery to change image opacity onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a 'gallery' of images with a selection button below each.  When I click on the button related to each image, I want the image opacity to change to 0.5.  I'd rather do this without each image having an individual id.  Warning: my jQuery knowledge is pretty average, I cant quite get my head around some of it!

```
<div>
    Group 1<br>
    <img src="http://www.example.com/myimage1.png" class="my-img" /><br>
    <button class="mybutton">Click</button>
</div>
<br>
<div>
    Group 2<br>
    <img src="http://www.example.com/myimage2.png" class="my-img" /><br>
    <button class="mybutton">Click</button>
</div>
```

So, with code like this, clicking any button will fade ALL images with that class, not just the related image

```
$('.mybutton').click(function(){
    $('.my-img').css("opacity","0.5");
});
```

I thought about using something like .prev() but I don't think I have my head wrapped around it properly and am implementing wrong.

```
$('.mybutton').click(function(){
    $(this).prev('.my-img').css("opacity","0.5");
});
```

Any thoughts on how to approach this?

https://jsfiddle.net/sanfly/gbkz566b/3/

Comment: Perhaps a little confusingly, `prev()` **always** targets the immediately-preceding element, despite the fact that it takes an argument. An argument passed to `.prev()` specifies that it should only trigger when the **immediately-preceding** element **also** matches the argument selector. In this case, it would only target the `<br>` tags that had the class `my-img` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) only gets the *immediately preceding sibling*, and that is the `<br>` tag. Your selector is looking for an element with the class `my-img`. As the `<br>` tag does not have this class the query wouldn't return anything.

Since there's only one button and image per parent you could use [`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) instead.

```js
$('.mybutton').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings('.my-img').css("opacity", "0.5");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Group 1<br>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl3Y0.png" class="my-img" /><br>
  <button class="mybutton">
Click
</button>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  Group 2<br>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl3Y0.png" class="my-img" /><br>
  <button class="mybutton">
Click
</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous element to the button is a `br`. So in this case you have to go to the root that is the parent and find the child that is img and change it's opacity

```js
$('.mybutton').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find('img.my-img').css("opacity", "0.5");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Group 1
  <br>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl3Y0.png" class="my-img" />
  <br>
  <button class="mybutton">
    Click
  </button>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  Group 2
  <br>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl3Y0.png" class="my-img" />
  <br>
  <button class="mybutton">
    Click
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, although this did work as well I have marked the .siblings() answer correct